# How do fix "(mousepad:1215): Gtk-WARNING **: 12:13:19.730: cannot open display: :0" error?

Tags: display, gtk, mousepad

When I tried to run this command "sudo mousepad /boot/config.txt" then analog@analog notice an error like this "(mousepad:1215): Gtk-WARNING **: 12:13:19.730: cannot open display: :0". I want to know what is happening to my equipment. And how can I fix it?

Comment: There is no info here that can be used to offer any help. https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask